# Android - best place to register/unregister broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-intentservice

I know there are tons of questions regarding this topic already, but I didn't find anything that matches my problem exactly.

### The Scenario

I have a `Button` in my `Fragment` which, when clicked, starts an `IntentService` and shows a `ProgressBar`. The `IntentService` does a network call that typically takes 5-10 seconds followed by `sendBroadcast()`. I remove the `ProgressBar` in `onReceive()` method of my `Fragment` implementing the `BroadcastReceiver` registered in `onResume()` and unregistered in `onPause()`

### The Problem

Say the user presses the `Button` and the `IntentService` is started. Before the `IntentService` sends the broadcast, the user does something like opening the Settings screen. Now my fragment is in `onStop()`. If the `IntentService` sends the broadcast right now, my `Fragment` will miss it and when user goes back, he will be greeted with a never ending `ProgressBar`.

I cannot move registering/unregistering to `onStart()`/`onStop()` either since opening Settings screen calls `onStop()` and the broadcast will still be missed.

This leaves me with `onCreate()`/`onDestroy()`. But the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) says there's no guarantee `onDestroy()` may be called. So I feel kind of lost as to where I should do my registering/unregistering.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using onPause() callBack

Comment: From the post - " I remove the ProgressBar in onReceive() method of my Fragment implementing the BroadcastReceiver registered in onResume() and unregistered in onPause()"

Comment: You're correct. A broadcast receiver should be registered in `onResume()` and unregistered in `onPause()`. Be sure to use `LocalBroadcastReceiver` for this. In order to address the issue you are seeing, I would use a static singleton, and a `volatile` boolean member which will be true while your service is running. You can check this value as you resume your Activity.

Comment: You can use a sticky intent for the broadcast, but you need permissions for this. What I generally do is have the IntentService send a broadcast and set a flag in shared preferences. This way you can check the shared preferences in onResume() to see if the Intent service is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can leave your fragment while the `IntenService` is running I'd recommend you to have a field in your `SharedPreferences`. Put a variable to `true` when your IntentService starts and change it to `false` when it finishes (just before your `sendBroadcast`).

In your fragment you can check everytime `onResume` register again the broadcast and then check in your `SharedPreferences` the value of your variable (in this order to prevent problems in getting the correct value due to multithreading).

Hope it helps

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach, but `onResume()` is called during screen rotation too. Reading `SharedPreferences` from the disk on each screen rotation sounds like not a good idea to me..

Comment: Another approach would be to create a static variable in your `IntentService` which could be accessed in a static way. You will prevent the disk access using this.

Comment: Marking your answer as correct since this is the approach I eventually followed. I moved register/unregister in onStart/onStop respectively.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in question you are register and unregister receiver in Fragment.

One better place is there.

```
@Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        // unregister here
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // register here
    }
```